# jquery ajax post data always Null at controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post, http-post

I am trying to post a viewmodel via Ajax, but it's always null once it reaches the controller?

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PreQulificationQuickSave([FromBody] VendorPreQualificationViewModel vm)
{
       return null;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".NavigationTab").click(function () {
            var VendorPreQualificationViewModel = {
                Id: $('#Id').val(),
                CompanyRegistrationName: $('#CompanyRegistrationName').val(),
                HoldingCompanyName : $('#HoldingCompanyName').val(),
                DateOfIncorporationEstablishment : $('#DateOfIncorporationEstablishment').val(),
                //NatureOfBusiness : 1,
                VendorNumber : $('#VendorNumber').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_FirstName : $('#ContactInformationSales_FirstName').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_LastName : $('#ContactInformationSales_LastName').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_JobTitle : $('#ContactInformationSales_JobTitle').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_ContactNumberLandLine : $('#ContactInformationSales_ContactNumberLandLine').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_ContactNumberMobile : $('#ContactInformationSales_ContactNumberMobile').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_FaxNumber : $('#ContactInformationSales_FaxNumber').val(),
                ContactInformationSales_Email : $('#ContactInformationSales_Email').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_FirstName : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_FirstName').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_LastName : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_LastName').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_JobTitle : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_JobTitle').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_ContactNumberLandLine : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_ContactNumberLandLine').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_ContactNumberMobile : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_ContactNumberMobile').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_FaxNumber : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_FaxNumber').val(),
                ContactInformationAccounts_Email : $('#ContactInformationAccounts_Email').val(),
                AddressType : $('#AddressType').val(),
                AddressName : $('#AddressName').val(),
                Address : $('#Address').val(),
                City : $('#City').val(),
                StateRegion : $('#StateRegion').val(),
                PostalCode : $('#PostalCode').val(),
                Country : $('#Country').val(),
                Currency : $('#Currency').val(),
                BEEExpirtyDate : $('#BEEExpirtyDate').val(),
                BEELevel : $('#BEELevel').val(),
                BEEEMEQSEGenericLarge : $('#BEEEMEQSEGenericLarge').val(),
                COIDCertificateNumber : $('#COIDCertificateNumber').val(),
                COIDExpirtyDate : $('#COIDExpirtyDate').val(),
                RelatedToSimeDarby : $('#RelatedToSimeDarby').val(),
                Remarks : $('#Remarks').val()
            };
            var vm = { "vm": VendorPreQualificationViewModel };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.PreQulificationQuickSave()',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: vm,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("some error");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My C# VendorPreQualificationViewModel contains all the same fields then the one in Javascript.
I have also tried JSON.Stringfy and JSON.Parse. I have always tried serializing the form with no luck.

Comment: I think here you are creating object of object. Try `data : VendorPreQualificationViewModel `

Comment: Still null when I pass in VendorPreQualificationViewModel

Comment: Remove [FromBody] from your api method

Comment: Removing [FromBody] and I get a 500 error status when trying to post